# Heuristic algorithm design techniques

Tags: ds.algorithms, reference-request, survey, books

I am looking for a good relatively complete and up-to-date book or survey about heuristic algorithm design techniques.

Comment: You might try "Local Search in Combinatorial Optimization" edited by Aarts and Lensta.

Comment: Have a look at work by Holger Hoos

Comment: too broad? by typical TCS interpretation includes entire field of [machine learning](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning)!

Comment: [DBLP](http://www.informatik.uni-trier.de/~ley/pers/hd/h/Hoos:Holger_H=) lists over 100 publications. Could you be more specific?